# Error when sorting scores of quiz numerically

Tags: python

For my coursework, I have been trying to sort the score file numerically and print it to python

I have tried to implement other answers from stackoverflow in to my code, but to no success.

This is the code I have:

```
if sortmethod == ("n"):
    with open(filename) as f:
        f = {}
        scores=[]
        for name, v in f.items():
            scores.append((name, score))
        for name, score in sorted(scores, key=lambda a: a[1], reverse=True):
            print(name, scores)
```

Thanks for the help.

Full code if needed:

```
import random
import operator

OPERATIONS = [
    (operator.add, "+"),
    (operator.mul, "*"),
    (operator.sub, "-")
    ]

NB_QUESTIONS = 10

def get_int_input(prompt=''):
    while True:
      try:
        return int(input(prompt))
      except ValueError:
        print("Not a valid input (integer is expected)")

def get_bool_input(prompt=''):
    while True:
        val = input(prompt).lower()
        if val == 'yes':
            return True
        elif val == 'no':
            return False
        else:
            print("Not a valid input (yes/no is expected)")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = input("What is your name?").title()
    class_name = input("Which class do you wish to input results for? ")
    print(name, ", Welcome to the OCR Controlled Assessment Maths Test")

    score = 0
    for _ in range(NB_QUESTIONS):
        num1 = random.randint(1,25)
        num2 = random.randint(1,25)
        op, symbol = random.choice(OPERATIONS)
        print("What is", num1, symbol, num2)
        if get_int_input() == op(num1, num2):
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")

    print("Well done", name, "you scored", score, "/", NB_QUESTIONS)

    filename = class_name + ".txt"

    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(name) + str(score) + '\n')

sortmethod = input("How do you wish to sort the scores. A = Alphabetically N = Numerically").lower()

if sortmethod == ("a"):
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f = open(filename, "r")
        lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
        f.close()
        lines.sort()

if sortmethod == ("n"):
    with open(filename) as f:
        f = {}
        scores=[]
        for name, v in f.items():
            scores.append((name, score))
        for name, score in sorted(scores, key=lambda a: a[1], reverse=True):
            print(name, scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are openning the file and putting the reference to it in `f` and then you are changing `f` to point to an empty dictionary. (In the following lines )-

```
 with open(filename) as f:
     f = {}
```

So scores would always be empty and you would never get anything printed.

I believe you should change the name of the diciotnary variable to something else, and then after openning the file, you should read it and put the values in the dictionary. We do not know how your file is structured so we cannot help you in that.

Also, you are doing similar things in other places , you should avoid doing such kinds of things -

```
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    f = open(filename, "r")
```

Also, another suggestion , when you are writing to your file in the following line -

```
f.write(str(name) + str(score) + '\n')
```

You are not putting any delimiter between your name and score, you should put some kind of delimiter there so that when reading back you can easily make out the name and scores. A Standard delimiters to use would be `comma - ','` .